# GWT - Fail to Read properties

Tags: file, gwt, properties, constants

When I run in hosted mode, it able to get the result.

But when I deploy it to tomcat then I cant get the result at all.

Anyone can tell me what is the problem??

public class Customwidget implements EntryPoint {

private static final SystemConfig constants = (SystemConfig)GWT.create(SystemConfig.class);

public void onModuleLoad() {
    Window.alert(constants.DBServerName());
}

SystemConfig.properties :
DBServerName=guaz

SystemConfig.java :
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Constants;

public interface SystemConfig extends Constants {
    String DBServerName();
    String DB_ServerName();
    String DB_PortNumber();
    String DB_DatabaseName();
    String DB_IntegratedSecurity();
    String DB_Password();
    String DB_User();
}

thanks

Comment: Are you getting any sort of error logged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your properties files must be located/copied in the **/WEB-INF/classes** subfolder of your web application.